# apacite bibliography (number in square brackets and bibliography heading)

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I have a document like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter} % charter font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{citeref}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliografia}
```

\begin{document}
For the same reasons, \citet{Parnas2003} have underlined the necessity of...

On the other hand, some authors \citep{Morgan2011} disagree with this view...

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}

I have two problems:

1. When it is produced the references list, it appears a "[1]" after each reference, like this:

   > Parnas, J., & Handest, P. (2003). Phenomenology of anomalous
   >   self-experience in early schizophrenia. Comprehensive psychiatry,
   >   44(2), 121–34. doi: 10.1053/comp.2003.50017 [1]

   I have checked the `apacite` documentation, but I didn't find nothing.
2. I can change the bibliography heading only using the book class. In the article class, `\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliografia}` doesn't work.

Someone could help me to find the source of this problems?

**EDIT** This are my bib entries:

```
@article{Parnas2003,
author = {Parnas, Josef and Handest, Peter},
doi = {10.1053/comp.2003.50017},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/Documenti/Psicologia/Papers/Phenomenology \& cognitive sciences/Self and schizophrenia/Ipseity-Hyperreflexivity model/Parnas, Handest - 2003 - Phenomenology of anomalous self-experience in early schizophrenia.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0010-440X},
journal = {Comprehensive psychiatry},
keywords = {Adult,Depersonalization,Disease Progression,Ego,Female,Humans,Male,Perceptual Disorders,Perceptual Disorders: psychology,Schizophrenic Psychology,Self Concept},
number = {2},
pages = {121--34},
pmid = {12658621},
title = {{Phenomenology of anomalous self-experience in early schizophrenia.}},
url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12658621},
volume = {44},
year = {2003}
}
```

@article{Morgan2011,
author = {Morgan, Hannah L and Turner, Danielle C and Corlett, Philip R and Absalom, Anthony R and Adapa, Ram and Arana, Fernando S and Pigott, Jennifer and Gardner, Jenny and Everitt, Jessica and Haggard, Patrick and Fletcher, Paul C},
doi = {10.1016/j.biopsych.2010.07.032},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/Documenti/Psicologia/Papers/Phenomenology \& cognitive sciences/Minimal self/Ownership/Morgan et al. - 2011 - Exploring the Impact of Ketamine on the Experience of Illusory.pdf:pdf},
issn = {1873-2402},
journal = {Biological psychiatry},
keywords = {Adult,Body Image,Female,Humans,Illusions,Illusions: drug effects,Infusions,Intravenous,Ketamine,Ketamine: administration \& dosage,Ketamine: blood,Ketamine: pharmacology,Male,Personality Assessment,Photic Stimulation,Placebos,Proprioception,Proprioception: drug effects,Psychiatric Status Rating Scales,Psychomotor Performance,Psychomotor Performance: drug effects,Touch Perception,Touch Perception: drug effects,Visual Perception,Visual Perception: drug effects},
month = jan,
number = {1},
pages = {35--41},
pmid = {20947068},
title = {{Exploring the impact of ketamine on the experience of illusory body ownership.}},
url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006322310008267 http://www.pubmedcentral.nih.gov/articlerender.fcgi?artid=3025328\&tool=pmcentrez\&rendertype=abstract},
volume = {69},
year = {2011}
}

Comment: Can you add the two entries as they are in the `.bib` file? For question 2 you should write `\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliografia}}`

Comment: Great! It works. I have edited with my two entries.

Comment: The number is due to `citeref`, that adds the pages where the reference is cited. Never load packages "because my friend says so". :)

Comment: I have deleted the .aux file (as you suggested me) and re-compiled, but the [1] still appear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7311/discussion-between-egreg-and-this-is-not-a-nick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is due to `citeref`, which adds the list of pages where the reference item has been cited.

Remove the call

```
\usepackage{citeref}
```

and, before recompiling, delete the `.aux` file, otherwise you'll get spurious errors due to the commands that are not recognized any more.

The `.aux` file will be automatically recreated. Run BibTeX again, just to be sure, and the number (back references) won't appear any more.

---

The renaming of the bibliography section is obtained by

```
\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliografia}}
```

because you're using `babel`.

Comment: I have the same issue over at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227010/discrepancy-in-using-apacite-for-bibliography - but I don't use the citeref package. Is it possible to kindly ask you to take a look at it?